# Match Excel Sheetnames with Openpyxl to Items in Pandas Column and return matches

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I am using Openpyxl to try and see if any of the sheet names are in a pandas dataframe column and return the matches without them repeating. Does anyone know how to do this? my current code is:

```
data_prep = load_workbook('file.xlsx',read_only=False, keep_vba= True)
empty=[]
y=df['x'].tolist()
for sheet in data_prep.sheetnames:
    empty.append(sheet)
    for i in empty:
        if i in y:
            print(i)
```

Comment: What's not working? What is `data_prep`? Your nested loop will lead to repetitions.

Comment: @CharlieClark thanks for pointing that  out. data_prep is the excel file I pulled using openpyxl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
columns = set(df['x'].tolist())
sheets = set(wb.sheetnames)
print(columns & sheets)
```

Comment: Thanks Charlie! This is great! so much simpler than mine as well